# Proposal for accept rate assignment?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, specific-question, unanswered-questions, accept-rate

Hello,
first of all I know that there are a lot of similar questions about this topic but it's difficult to see if my concern was already processed.
At the moment I have an accept rate at Superuser under 80 and it's getting worse because you could say you will be punished when you ask questions where almost nobody has an answer. Sometimes you only get one answer which didn't solve your very special problem. So you can say the more difficult your question will be, the less is the chance to get a satisfying answer and hence you accept rate falls more and more. You have the possibility to delete you unanswered question to save your accept rate, but that doesn't help other people with a similar problem. Or you answer your own unanswered question to not lose much more of your accept rate. Moreover you prevent people of posting possible helpful answers.

I have a proposal for that problem. The accept rate should not be decreased as long as you write comments to every (unsatisfying) answer (to give an overview why this solution didn't solve your problem). So if you have 3 answers, and these answers didn't solve your problem, you could write at least one comment to every answer. That shows that you are still interested on your question and it also shows that you did not leave your question unanswered. This method would be very fair to everybody. Wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 2):

Three different remarks:

**First**

You can't get decent answers to most of your questions on SuperUser.

This problem should probably be discussed on meta.superuser

**Second**

There's a problem with your suggestion. What if you:

1. Ask a question.
2. Get an answer, and a good one
3. Write a comment saying: "That did the trick, thanks!"
4. Forget to accept, and leave

Exactly how would you implement a mechanism to differ the comment like this and the comment like you described.

I think the main problem is with ability to find good answers on SU. It shouldn't be solved with changes on the voting/accepting system.

**Third**

I've noticed that you have many Ubuntu related questions on SU. Try asking them on AskUbuntu. People there will actually understand what are you asking them. Posted on SU, your questions are buried under tons of Windows specific questions and many other things including hardware..

Comment: Oops, I thought that there is only one "meta-overflow" for SU, SO, and Serverfault. :) But actually it's a common issue and not especially related to SU. 
Anyway, ok you are right with your answer. But maybe there could be some kind of reminder-mechanism which notifies you if you want to answer any of your unanswered questions after a given time period?